# Quantile Regression with exponential sum of independent variables

Tags: python, statsmodels, quantile-regression

I would like to fit a quantile regression to my data (time series) as a function of some harmonics. This is to smooth out the time variability of the quantiles.

The harmonics are simply:

```
nu = 2*np.pi/tau
h1 = np.sin(1* nu * x)
h2 = np.cos(1* nu * x)
h3 = np.sin(2* nu * x)
h4 = np.cos(2* nu * x)
```

The most straightforward formula is:

```
modqr = smf.quantreg('y ~ h1+h2+h3+h4', data)
```

from this `modqr` I fit the model as:

```
res = modqr.fit(q=0.8)
```

`res` will have 5 coefficients, an intercept and the 4 coefficients of my harmonics.

However, I need my y to be non-negative, so one simple transformation could be something like:

```
modqr = smf.quantreg('y ~ np.exp(h1+h2+h3+h4)', data)
```

which is with `y` as a function of the exponential of the sum of the harmonics.

If I use this formula, however, the results will be 2 parameters only, of course, one for the Intercept, and one for the term `np.exp(h1+h2+h3+h4)`, which is seen as a unique independent variable.

Q: Is there a way to write this formula to trick quantreg to evaluate the exponential of the sum of my harmonics, therefore still giving me 5 parameters?

I thought that I could pass a transformation of my independent variables formula in a similar way to when I pass the `family=Poisson()` kwargs when I fit the poisson regression, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Not sure fitting harmonics in data space is good idea. Typical approach is to do FFT into frequency domain, and look for peak at frequency 1w, 2w, 3w etc

Comment: thanks for this comment. it made me realize I was maybe not clear in the question, I will edit it. It is as a function of time. x = time. It essentially serves to simplify the seasonal cycle.